# CSS gradient not rendering in Windows Phone 8 WebBrowser Control

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

I am facing an issue where, the CSS3 background is not rendered in WebBrowser control in Windows Phone 8. But same HTML when opened in WebBrowser in Windows Phone 8, it rendered the gradient

The HTML I am using is:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px;overflow:hidden;"> 
            <div id="im_c" style="height:48px;width:100%25;  background: -ms-linear-gradient(
                 bottom,                
                 #432100 30%,               
                 #00AAAA 70%);"> 
                <div style="margin:0 auto;width:320px;">
                    Test
                    </div> 

            </div> 
            <style> 
                body {margin:0px} 
            </style> 
    </body>
</html>
```

In Windows Phone 8, I use the HTML as below:

```
WebView.NavigateToString(@"<html><head><meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=320, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1""/></head><body style=""margin:0px;overflow:hidden;""> <div id=""im_c"" style=""height:48px;width:100%25; background: -ms-linear-gradient(         bottom,                 #432100 30%,                #00AAAA 70%);""> <div style=""margin:0 auto;width:320px;"">Test</div></div> <style> body {margin:0px} </style> </body></html>");
```

Can any one help here?

Thanks
SRS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like, I fixed the issue.

I added  to the HTML and now it renders it properly.

Thanks